# Pandas, turn all the data frame to unique categorical values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I am relatively new to Pandas and to python and I am trying to find out how to turn all content(all fields are strings) of a Pandas Dataframe to categorical one.

All the values from rows and columns have to be treated as a big unique data set before turning them to categorical numbers.

So far I was able to write the following piece of code

```
for col_name in X.columns:
    if(X[col_name].dtype == 'object'):
        X[col_name]= X[col_name].astype('category')
        X[col_name] = X[col_name].cat.codes
```

that works on a data frame X of multiple columns. It takes the strings and turns them to unique numbers.

What I am not sure for the code above is that my for loop only works per column and I am not sure if the codes assigned are unique per column or per whole data frame (the latter is the desired action).

Can you please provide advice on how I can turn my code to provide unique numbers considering all the values of the data frame?

I would like to thank you in advance for your help.
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for set `MultiIndex Series` to unique values:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].stack().astype('category').cat.codes.unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work to assign unique codes based on the whole data frame. How I can check the mapping between codes and the initial strings?